# Send and Execute maxscript or python from Maya to 3ds Max

Tags: python, maya, 3dsmax, maxscript

I am wondering if there is a method to connect 3ds Max and Maya. For example, I want to use a Maya plugin to send a maxscript to 3ds Max to import an fbx in 3ds max. I think it just like `send to Max` function in Maya, and it seems like the `OneClickDispatch` does similar work, but I do not how OneClickDispatch sends the script to 3ds max and execute it. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way to do this IN to Maya is to write a script to a temp location, use a socket to connect to Maya's listen port and use python/mel to execute the commands in the temp script file. I can only assume something similar would work for Max, but have no first-hand knowledge there

Comment: If this is just a personal productivity tool for yourself, you might be satisfied with something stupendously basic.  Instead of messing around with sockets for communication, why not simply have a script that has a [timer](http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-9A4F0A09-BB42-4EED-95CC-6B3D06939640) which periodically looks for a file somewhere?  The contents of the file could perhaps just contain the path to the FBX you want to import.

Answer (score 0):

For example SublimeEditor is doing it by finding 3dsMax window handle, then is finding handle of childwindow "Scintilla" - maxscript listener, send text there, like `filein @"X:\location\to\your\temp\script"` and then return char - should be easy to snitch from Sublime, otherwise you have to be quite familiar with Windows ShellApi